# javascript coding style functions comma separated and "this"

Tags: javascript

When I am seeing JavaScript code with functions comma separated. I tend to not like that. Is it becoming more normal and is `this` getting MORE objects?

e.g.

```
function PerformanceScorecardGrid(jQ, dM, container, resources) {
   var self = this,
    applyStyles = function () {
        // This is a workaround to get the table background for the radial first column to adjust to kendo redraws.
        jQ('body table').css('background-size', (jQ('table tbody tr td:first-of-type').outerWidth() + 1) + 'px ' + (jQ('table tbody').height() + jQ('table tfoot').outerHeight() + 1) + 'px');
        jQ('body table').css('background-position', '0 ' + jQ('table thead').outerHeight() + 'px');
    },
    appendHeaderRowToTable = function(table, headerRow, columnCount) {  

       var newRow = jQ('<tr>').addClass('ps-norm-row'); // TODO: Add condition to check if norm/goal row

        // Create column template
        var columnTemplate = jQ('<th>').attr('role', 'columnheader').addClass('k-header');
        // ...... 

    },
    appendFooterRowToTable = function(table, footerRow, columnCount) {
        // ......

}
```

1. `self = this` Is the reason the author went with "self" is to have a "better" word ?
2. Is `this (self)` containing more data (objects) when function returns are comma separated?
3. What advantages and disadvantages are there in this style?
4. From the function input parameters, it seems difficult for ME to understand what "this" contains  (self)

Thoughts?

thx in advance.

Comment: Assigning `this` to a variable makes it possible to use that value inside functions declared in the same scope, whereas the `this` keyword might have a different meaning there (Google: "this closure").

Comment: 1) `self` is common, so is `_this`. 2) No 3) Personal preference

Comment: I noticed another js file that is a IIFE , and it makes a call to this code above like  `var grid = new PerformanceScorecardGrid(jQ, dM, $container, resources);`       What will "grid" contain ?

Comment: It is recommended to have var's separately defined, rather than on the same line like that. It's sheer laziness and harder to maintain.

Comment: I realize that I don't have all the js code pasted above,  as there is a lot of kendo ui grid code ..

Comment: Yes, you rather should use function declarations instead of expressions in a multiline `var` declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: self = this is the reason the author went with "self" is to have a "better" word ?

A: no, this is a construct to be able to use `this` from the outer function in the inner functions (they have "own" `this`)

Q: Is "this" (self) containing "more" data (objects) when function returns are comma separated?
What advantages and disadvantages are there in this style?

A: `this` contains always a value passed when invoking the function. There are no function returns, only function expressions in the code snippet. Regarding `this` see e.g. http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/, http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp

Q: From the function input parameters, it seems difficult for ME to understand what "this" contains (self)

A: see previous answer.

Btw. the commas "between functions" are a way how to not write extra `var` for each variable.